# Safari popup slow appearing

Tags: javascript, safari, popup

When I click on a submit button to open a popup window in Safari (8.0.5) on Yosemite (10.10.3) there is a few second delay before the window pops up.  Some simple code that shows this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "winName", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>Popped!</p>");
    myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The first time the popup is opened there is a delay.  After that, if the popup is left open, there is no delay.  If I close the popup then the delay comes back when the request to recreate the popup is done.  window.open is consistently taking about 3 seconds when it needs to create a new popup window.
I've tried disabling caches, turning off extensions, ... all to no avail.  On Firefox and Chrome the new window appears immediately.

Any ideas what is going on?  How the delay can be avoided?

Thank you.

Comment: We are seeing a very similar issue at the moment too. Not sure there is a decent answer/work around, debugging seems to show the event just takes a long time to get picked up by Safari. We've started opening our item in a tab for now.

Comment: I only see it on Safari.  I haven't seen anything about it on Apple sites but you'd think there would be some complaints.  Thanks for commenting - at least I now know I'm not hallucinating.

Comment: It is only Safari for us too, all other browsers are fine.